# mysql php function doesn't return value

Tags: php, mysql

Why doesn't this function do't return any row?

```
function select_mysql($tabel, $order, $volgorder, $statement) {
  $iCount = 0;
  $rows = array();
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $tabel . ' ' . $statement . 
           ' ORDER BY `' . $order . '` ' . $volgorder . '';
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    while ($property = mysql_fetch_field($result)) {
      $rows[$iCount][$property->name] = $row[$property->name];
    }

    $iCount++;
  }
  return $rows;
}
```

Comment: I don't know. What does the query look like?

Comment: Are you sure that the query is valid? Try to insert `echo $query` and look at the result.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for the `mysql_fetch_field()` inner loop. `$row` will be an associative array with all the row's field's in it. So if you've got fields `a`, `b`, `c` in that table, then you can access them with `$row['a']`, `$row['b']`, and `$row['c']`.